# Vanity URL rerouting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to allow for users on a website to specify and change their own unique Vanity Url.

I am going to store the chose url within the database and I want to call upon it to re-route to the user.

As of now this is what I have, but I am not really sure where to go from here.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "User", // Route name
            "User/Profile/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "User", action = "Profile", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { typeof(MvcApplication).Namespace + ".Controllers" }
        );
```

Is there any way for me to take in the Vanity Url and reroute it to the PersonID?

I also tried to Manipulate the ActionResult to either handle the string Vanity Url or the int PersonID but that did not seem to be going in the right direction so I went back to routes.Maproute.

Edit:

I want the user to be able to enter in

```
http://localhost:60619/User/Profile/Vanity
```

and they will end up in the same place as if they entered

```
http://localhost:60619/User/Profile/224 Assuming the PersonID is 224
```

ActionResult:

```
        public ActionResult Profile(int ID)
    {
        ppUser viewerChoice = DB.ppUser_GetUserByPersonID(ID);
        return View(ID);
    }
```

Comment: provide us with a *sample url* and the signature for the related `action method`

Comment: Ok, I added it in an edit (I think)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that the vanity URL will NOT reroute to a separate view per user based on the URL.

Instead the vanity URL will route all users to the same view, and the view content will change based on the value of the vanity URL. In this case the vanity URL works exactly like a database ID.

For example:

- ://xxx/User/Profile/Mike
- ://xxx/User/Profile/Steve
- ://xxx/User/Profile/Peter
- ://xxx/User/Profile/Sonia

Will all route the same view.

So the code inside the controller will load the content based on Mike, Steve, Peter, etc.

This will be the equivalent of loading the content based on profile id 24,56,88, etc.

You have to guarantee that the vanity URL is unique, just like the profile ID

Here is a sample on how to create the table:

```
USE [mydb]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Vanity]    Script Date: 05/30/2012 13:53:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vanity](
    [ProfileID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VanityURL] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Vanity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfileID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


USE [mydb]
/****** Object:  Index [IX_Vanity]    Script Date: 05/30/2012 13:53:57 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Vanity] ON [dbo].[Vanity] 
(
    [VanityURL] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vanity]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Vanity_Vanity] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Vanity] ([ProfileID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vanity] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Vanity_Vanity]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this it worked for me, by using below code you can place two different pages on a single domain by just differentiating there

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", "{Id}", "~/User.aspx");
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", "Home", "~/Default.aspx");
    }
```